# Перебор в цикле строк из файла PHP

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста, необходимо сделать цикл, который будет проверять определенный столбец передаваемого файла с условием, есть ли в данном столбце значение больше 0.

То есть приходит файл, там идут значения
0
0
0
1
видит 1, значит все нормально, гружу данные в БД

если приходит файл со значениями
0
0
0
0
то данные в БД не загружаю.

вот у меня реализовано пока так, но в данном случае, как только видит данные с нулем, сразу выбивает ошибку.

```
function upload($p_file){

$uploaddir = './load/';
 // yyyy/mm/dd
 $uploaddir .= date('Y/n/d/');
 mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . date("dmYHis", time()) . '_' . rnd(10) . '_' . basename($p_file['name']);

 if (move_uploaded_file($p_file['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
 } else {
  $error_string = "Не могу скопировать файл в load директорию";
  $error = true;
  return;
 }

 $file_name = $uploadfile;
 $csv = array();

 $f = fopen($file_name, "rt");
 while (($buffer = fgets($f, 10000)) !== false) {
  $buffer = trim($buffer,"\n\r");
  $data = str_getcsv($buffer,";");
  $csv[] = $data;
 }

 fclose($f);

$sql = "call web_t(?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($page->mysqli_handle, $sql);
    foreach($csv as $key => $csv_row){

        if($key > 0)
 {
            $clm = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $csv_row[3]));
if($clm == 0)
        {
            $error_string = "Все данные равны нулю";
            $error = true;
            return;
        }

// грузим в базу.
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'd', $clm);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            if ($result == false)
            {
                $error_string = "ERROR[web_t($key)]: " . mysqli_error($page->mysqli_handle);
                $error = true;
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

А необходимо чтобы весь файл проверяло на значение больше нуля, если есть хоть одно значение больше 0, тогда данные загружаем.

Если есть варианты как это реализовать без цикла, тоже приветсвуется.

Comment: не понятна суть вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, правильно вас понял.

```
$array = array(0, 0, 1, 0); //Пришедшие данные
foreach($array as $key => $value) { //Идем по массиву
    if($value) { //Если текущее значение не ноль. Учтите, если придет отрицательное число, то условие выполнится; если Вас это не устраивает - используйте ($value > 0)
        //Здесь используйте код для загрузки массива на сервер
        break;
    }
}
```

Попробуйте так:

```
function upload($p_file) {

    $uploaddir = './load/';
    $uploaddir .= date('Y/n/d/');
    mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . date("dmYHis", time()) . '_' . rnd(10) . '_' . basename($p_file['name']);

    if(!move_uploaded_file($p_file['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $error_string = "Не могу скопировать файл в load директорию";
        $error = true;
        return;
    }

    $csv = null;

    $f = fopen($file_name, "rt");
    while (($buffer = fgets($f, 10000)) !== false) {
        $buffer = trim($buffer,"\n\r");
        $data = str_getcsv($buffer,";");
        $csv += $data;
    }
    fclose($f);

    $sql = "call web_t(?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($page->mysqli_handle, $sql);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($csv); i++) {
        if($csv[i] > 0) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'd', $csv);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                $error_string = "ERROR[web_t($key)]: " . mysqli_error($page->mysqli_handle);
                $error = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    $error_string = "Все данные равны нулю";
    $error = true;
    return;
}
```

Comment: `$array = array(0, 0, 1, 0); if (in_array(1, $array)) { die("Можно..."); }` - так буде проще и короче

Comment: Пожалуй. Однако, как я понял, нужно смотреть на все, что больше нуля.

Comment: мне необходимо проверять элемент массива $csv_row[3] 
данные могут приходит разные, не только 0 и 1.

$array = array(0, 0, 1, 0); if (in_array(1, $array)) { die("Можно..."); } 
как в данную проверку добавить условие на проверку элемента массива $csv_row[3], есть ли значение больше 0?

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ - это учтено. Не удалось найти код функции `in_array()`,- может, займусь этим позже,- но вполне вероятно, что она попросту идет циклом по массиву и ищет нужное значение.

Comment: @Marionette К сожалению, все равно не могу понять как он будет проверять на значения выше нуля? Подскажите пожалуйста.
  foreach($csv_row[3] as $k => $value){
                if ($value)
                     die("Можно загружать данные на сервер");
            }
и для чего здесь die? мне необходимо чтобы он проверил массив, и потом проверенный массив загрузить в БД.

Comment: В `foreach()` нужно передать полученный массив, а Вы объявляете новую переменную, при этом не описываете ее. Замените `die()` на код, который выполнит загрузку массива на сервер. Как вы получаете массив для проверки?

Comment: `$csv_row` - это массив целых чисел или строка? Опишите вопрос более подробно, представьте код загрузки на сервер и получения массива данных.

Comment: @Marionette доброе утро. Код оставил в вопросе, т.к. в комментарии он не влезает. Вопрос стоит в этом месте 
$clm = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $csv_row[3]));
if($clm == 0)
        {
            $error_string = "Все данные равны нулю";
            $error = true;
            return;
        }
У меня перебирает весь файл, но как видит хоть одно значение равное нулю, выбивает ошибку.
А надо чтобы проверяло весь файл, и если есть хоть одно значение выше нуля, тогда все хорошо и данные грузились в БД.
например 
0
0
0
такие данные пришли, не грузим.
0
0
0
0.1 !! Грузим.

Comment: Обновил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: @Marionette спасибо большое за ответ, ну это к сожалению не совсем то, 
strlen возвращает длину строки, ну в строку может придти все значения равные 0. В таком случае он видит что в строку пришел символ 0.
Ваш вариант отлично бы работал если бы в строку приходили пустые значения.

Comment: А что не так? Цикл проверяет строку на наличие значений больше нуля и, если такие есть, загружает данные на сервер. Разве задача не в этом?

Comment: @Marionette Тут надо чтобы весь массив был проверен, и если хоть одно значение было выше 0, тогда данные грузились, иначе выдавало ошибку.
Может есть что то с exists? как в mysql :)

Comment: Именно так код и работает. Он полностью считывает данные из файла, а после они передаются в цикл для проверки на наличие значения больше нуля. Если такое нашлось - строка загружается на сервер, иначе цикл пройдет по всей строке и выдаст ошибку.

Comment: @Marionette может я уже что то не понимаю, ну strlen — Возвращает длину строки. Когда в строке приходит цифра 0, тогда длинна строки уже 1 символ. И если придут значения 0, 0, 0, 0, то данные все равно загрузятся, т.к. всегда возвращает длину строки 1 символ.

Comment: strlen() устанавливает необходимое количество итераций, чтобы проверить каждый символ. Предположим, в файле "0000", тогда strlen() вернет 4, то есть выполнится 4 итерации, но данные не будут загружены, поскольку все символы меньше единицы `($csv[i] > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = "0101";
$len = strlen($num);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    if($num[$i] > 0 ){
        $exist = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($exist) echo "была найдена единица";
```

Если неподходит то напишите и я поправлю

Comment: К сожалению, не работает.
Данные грузятся если указать в столбец все нули.
Можно с вами как то связаться на прямую?

Comment: @БогданЛисовский, вам уже дали решение ниже, с `foreach`, в чем проблема?

Comment: c foreach не работает
апач ругается на - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
с вардампа получаю string(1) "1"
вот код
var_dump($lat);
foreach($lat as $k => $value) {
                if($value) 
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'd',$lat);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем большое.
А так же отдельное спасибо @Marionette
Сделал по своему..
Вообщем как я и писал ранее, когда грузят файл, я его передаю в переменную. В этой переменной есть нужные мне элементы которые мне надо проверять на наличие числа больше 0.
Вообще создал отдельную функцию на проверку нулей.

```
function check_zeros($p_csv){
    foreach ($p_csv as $row ) {
        if($row[3] != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if($row[5] != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

И далее я ее вызываю с проверкой на false.

```
if(check_zeros($csv) == false)
{
    $error_string = "Все значения равны нулю";
    $error = true;
    return;
}
```

Выходит то, что мне требовалось, если есть значения больше нуля, то все нормально, файл проходит проверку и загружается.